# wanderlust: getting application/octet-stream images to display?

Tags: images, wanderlust

In wanderlust, if an attachment has an `image/*` content type, the image will be properly displayed in the message buffer. For example ...

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="foobar.jpg"
```

However, some emails arrive with their attachment's content type set to `application/octet-stream`, even though the attachment is an image, and wanderlust will not display these images in the message buffer. For example ...

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="foobar.jpg"
```

Is there any way to configure wanderlust so that it uses the `name` attribute to determine that an octet stream represents an image, so it can be displayed in the message buffer?

Comment: Have a look at all of the references to `(ctree-set-calist-strictly ...)`

Comment: Thank you. As far as I can tell, `ctree-set-calist-strictly` seems to ignore the `name="..."` attribute in `Content-Type`. Actually, the entire MIME parsing system under `semi` seems to ignore that attribute ... unless I'm missing something.

Comment: While I have not played with your specific fact pattern, I have set up PDF to be displayed as images after being converted to PNG and I had to remove or comment out `(ctree-set-calist-strictly 'mime-preview-condition '((body . visible) (body-presentation-method . mime-display-text/plain)))`  After commenting out that section, I was able to use `(ctree-set-calist-strictly 'mime-preview-condition '((type . application) (subtype . pdf) (body . visible) (body-presentation-method . mime-display-image) (image-format . pdf)))`  Perhaps the same section of code that I commented out also affects you?

Comment: Actually, in looking through the `semi/mime-*.el` stuff, I realized that I could do what I want by modifying the `mime-entity-situation` function. Your pointing me to `ctree-set-calist-strictly` got me onto the right track, so thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by hacking `mime-entity-situation`, as follows ...

```
(defun my-mime-imagetype (fname)
  (let (imtype
        mime-info
        subtype)
    (when (stringp fname)
      (setq mime-info (mime-find-file-type fname))
      (and (string-equal (car mime-info) "image")
           (setq subtype (car (cdr mime-info)))
           (setq imtype (intern subtype))))
    imtype))

(defun my-mime-entity-situation (oldfunc &rest args)
  (let* ((result   (apply oldfunc args))
         (filename (cdr (assq 'filename result)))
         (type     (cdr (assq 'type     result)))
         (subtype  (cdr (assq 'subtype  result)))
         imtype)
    (when (and (eq type    'application)
               (eq subtype 'octet-stream)
               (setq imtype (my-mime-imagetype filename)))
      (setf (alist-get 'type    result) 'image)
      (setf (alist-get 'subtype result) imtype))
    result))
(advice-add 'mime-entity-situation :around #'my-mime-entity-situation)
```